# Input field not required (nullable) Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I'm having an issue with my contact form. All the fields are required except for one field. Normally I would in migration insert nullable, but apparently, it doesn't work. I have tried to make a nullable in validation, but this doesn't work either. So I'm a bit confused.

```html
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('kontaktforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('navn');
        $table->string('mobilnr');
        $table->string('fastnetnr')->nullable();
        $table->string('mail');
        $table->string('emne');
        $table->text('beskrivelse');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```html
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'navn' => 'required',
            'mobil' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'emne' => 'required',
            'beskrivelse' => 'required'
        ]);


        $kontakt = new Kontaktform([
            'navn'  => $request['navn'],
            'mobilnr' => $request['mobil'],
            'fastnetnr' => $request['fastnetnr'],
            'mail' => $request['email'],
            'emne' => $request['emne'],
            'beskrivelse' => $request['beskrivelse']
        ]);
        $kontakt->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Vi har nu modtaget din besked');
        return redirect()->route('kontakt.create');
    }
```

Form

```html
<form id="form-contact" action="{{route('kontakt.store')}}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <h1 class="display-4">Kontakt os</h1>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="navn" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit navn...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="mobil" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Din mobil">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="fastnetnr" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Evt fastnetnr">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Din email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="emne" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Emne">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="beskrivelse" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv din besked her" rows="4"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Send">
                        <hr>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried, and what happens when you try it.

Comment: did you already `migrate:refresh` the database?

Comment: Yes. I made a migrate:fresh :) It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but the table `kontaktforms` does not have any field called `fastnetnr` which you are trying to enter from your controller.

Maybe add the field in the migration, run migration again after rolling back and then try?

Comment: That was the issue. And I made a migration fresh and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Do migration for nullable field as

```
$table->string('fieldname')->nullable();
```

and during validation either by using **Validator** or **FormRequest** confirm that you haven't added a required attribute

```
'fieldname' => 'required|integer'
```

you must have only

```
'fieldname' => 'integer'
```

Comment: if this worked for you then check a tick mark to accept the answer so the answer might be helpful for others

Comment: you don't have a fastnetnummer field in you migration table

Comment: had you run rolled back and migrate again - php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your attention. I appreciate your help!